# Override $argv for getopt

Tags: php

example.php:

```
$args = __FILE__.' -vvv';
$argv = explode(' ', $args);
$argc = count($argv);
$GLOBALS['argv'] = $_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;
$GLOBALS['argc'] = $_SERVER['argc'] = $argc;

var_export(getopt('v'));
```

> $ example.php -v
>
> > array('v' => false);

Eventually `getopt` does not look up to `$GLOBALS` to get `argv`. So it there any way I can override `argv` array?

Comment: I don't think its possible to change the arguments that `getopt()` is using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## TL;DR

No, there is no native way to do this. Depending of your goals there may be other ways to resolve the issue, but overriding is not one of them.

## Operating on super-globals

**Structure**

To realize why it is so, you should know, that super-globals are not just "variables" to which you are referring. That means, if you are using `$argv` to de-reference arguments list, it *does not* mean that you'll access some data which is stored **in "variable"** `$argv`. Instead, you'll access to data container by "link", called `$argv`. However, there are different ways to access this data - `$_SERVER['argv']` or `$GLOBALS` array at least. To illustrate, I'll go with the code:

```
var_dump($argv, $_SERVER['argv']);
unset($argv);
var_dump($argv, $_SERVER['argv']);
```

This will result in something like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "example.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "-vvv"
}//&lt;--------------------- derived from $argv
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "example.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "-vvv"
}//&lt;--------------------- derived from $_SERVER['argv']
NULL//&lt;------------------ we've unset $argv, so unset a reference
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "example.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "-vvv"
}//&lt;--------------------- but data is still there and available via another reference
```

**Internally**

As you can see, the reference can be destroyed, but actual data will remain untouched. That will be stored in [symbols table](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/Zend/zend_globals.h#L178). Many PHP functions are accessing this structure to retrieve data, and [`getopt()`](http://php.net/getopt) is not an exception. So the conclusion is - yes, you can modify the reference (or even destroy it), but actual data will be still in super-globals.

## `getopt()`

Now, about this function. Just take a look at its [implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4269):

```
/* Get argv from the global symbol table. We calculate argc ourselves
 * in order to be on the safe side, even though it is also available
 * from the symbol table. */
if (PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_SERVER] &&
    (zend_hash_find(HASH_OF(PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_SERVER]), "argv", sizeof("argv"), (void **) &args) != FAILURE ||
    zend_hash_find(&EG(symbol_table), "argv", sizeof("argv"), (void **) &args) != FAILURE) && Z_TYPE_PP(args) == IS_ARRAY
) 
{
    //...omitted
}
```

It's clearly stated, that it will try to search `"argv"` in `symbol_table` (if you want - here's a link to - [how](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/Zend/zend_hash.c#L913) it will be done exactly). And that means - it will access actual data, thus, overriding it externally will have no effect.

As a result - `getopt()` will work with data which were gathered at script startup, and that data will contain actual parameters, no matter if you'll override them inside your script.